# Adding Custom Fields to Devise Registration - Ruby on Rails 4 & Devise 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi, I have a model Coach that I'm trying to add specific fields to. I have created a migration and added the fields to the registration but receive the error
 **NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new** &  **undefined method `first_name' for**

**Thank You for taking a look at this...**

 Update: I have already migrated the database
 Here is what my code looks like thus far:

#### Registration

### Sign up as a Coach

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>


  <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "coaches/shared/links" %>
```

#### Migration

```
class AddFieldsToCoaches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  end
end
```

#### Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140627044906) do

  create_table "coaches", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "coaches", ["email"], name: "index_coaches_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "coaches", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_coaches_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "players", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "players", ["email"], name: "index_players_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "players", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_players_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

#### Back Trace

```
Started GET "/coaches/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-27 00:50:41 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered coaches/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for #<Coach:0x007f9f874d6510>):
     5:     
     6:     
     7:   <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
     8:   <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %></div>
     9:   
    10:   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    11:   <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>
  app/views/coaches/registrations/new.html.erb:8:in `block in _app_views_coaches_registrations_new_html_erb__1603382164571940584_70161540751300'
  app/views/coaches/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_coaches_registrations_new_html_erb__1603382164571940584_70161540751300'


  Rendered /Users/noahreisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/noahreisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/noahreisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (9.8ms)
```

Comment: have you migrated the table? `rake db:migrate`

Comment: @WaliAli Yes, I have done so.

Comment: first make sure the fields have been added to the coaches table by checking schema or `rails c`. is what you posted above one error message or two different errors? I noticed `&`. I just added `first_name` to a devise `User` table (rails 4) by simply running migration and it worked. add strong parameters as the answer below suggested.

Comment: Can You present model's class for user? Why is migration named "...Coach" but tabel - "users"

Comment: There is no User model, strictly Coach.rb because there is another separate model Player.rb - I changed the migration from add_column :users, :first_name, :string to => add_column :coaches, :first_name, :string. However there was no change. As for the error. The error is "undefined method `first_name'"

Comment: And show full backtrace

Comment: backtrace? The error outputted by the terminal?

Comment: You wrote:"NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new & undefined method `first_name' for ..." I need something that after "for"

Comment: Yeah, as in, the error was rooted in Devise registrations as a result of undefined method 'first_name'? What am I not following?

Comment: yes, backtrace is the error outputed by the terminal. you can edit your question and include it. also post the table from schema (`db/schema.rb`).

Comment: Do you have base class for users?. Ideally, You should have class User and class Player and Coach should be inherited from User

Comment: You have 3 tabele players, couchs and users, but added field only for users

Comment: I originally had a user model, but destroyed that model and went with 2 separate models because they will have quite contrasting fields. What do you mean by "only added fields for users" i added class AddFieldsToCoaches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :coaches, :first_name, :string
    add_column :coaches, :last_name, :string
  end
end

Comment: @MaxKonin    What do you mean by "Remove Tables players and coaches" can you elaborate? And with this methodology will I still be able to have a separate registration form for Player and Coach

Comment: @MaxKonin I sincerely appreciate you spending time on this question of mine. However, I feel a bit inundated by all the different approaches. Can you please just give a simplified approach to where i can have separate registration forms for Coach and Player while being able to customize their registrations. Again Thank you.

Comment: For separate registration form for Player and Coach you should use scoped veiw (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)

Comment: Okay i will go ahead and follow that, thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be problem with Strong Parameters. Try to add following code to application_controller.rb.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
  end
end
```

For more information: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: I believe it may be an issue with strong parameters but adding that to the ApplicationController did not fix it! Any other ideas?

Comment: @NJay : have you added those parameters in model as well??

Answer (score 1):

Modify your modals:
1. Create base class User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #configs for devise
end
```

1. Inherit Couch and Players from User

   `class Player < User; end`

   `class Couch < User; end`
2. Remove Tabels players and couchs

   drop_table :players

If you do not want to use STI. You can use MTI But it is not good way.

You can add separate devise's routes for couchs and players to routes.rb:

```
devise_for :couchs, :players
```

But it's best to use the STI

Comment: What do you mean by "Remove Tables players and coaches" can you elaborate? And with this methodology will I still be able to have a separate registration form for Player and Coach

Comment: For separate registration form for Player and Coach you should use scoped veiw (github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)

Comment: got it working by deleting users table in the schema and rails destroy devise User then like you said the addition of the methods into the application controller!

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for #<Coach:0x007f9f874d6510>):
```

what this error is telling you is `first_name` is not an attribute of `Coach`.

As you can see from the `schema` you posted, the `coaches table` does not have the `first_name` field. so this means you haven't properly added the `first_name` to the table.

to add the field to the table, do this:

`rails g migration AddFirstNameToCoach first_name:string`

then run `rake db:migrate`

then implement @MaxKonin answer about permitting additional parameters

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

And you have to do the same for sign_in and account_update

ApplicationController

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```